# oauth while learning various twitter methods

Tags: oauth, twitter

I'm experimenting with this method "users lookup" from the Twitter API.  Is there any way I can directly type the url in the browser and see the results?  I am logged into Twitter, but I get the error message "basic authentication is not supported" when I type 
http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.xml?user_id=12863272,3191321,9160152,8285392 (this is from their documentation page).  What do I need to do to experiment with the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are <s>four</s> three options:

### Option 1.

Write an application you can use to talk to twitter.

### <s>Option 2.</s>

Use cUrl with a lot copy and pasting.

### Option 3.

http://thechangelog.com/post/536535280/twurl-oauth-enabled-curl-for-the-twitter-api

### Option 4.

http://dev.twitter.com/console

Comment: You need to copy and paste the OAuth tokens.

Comment: I didn't understand.  I am using a script/cron job to get my data, so console wouldn't be useful to me.  Is there any way to pass OAuth tokens in the URL?

Comment: If using a script, simply install Twurl (option 3) and use Twurl. It's that simple.

Comment: is there no way to not depend on external tools? I mean, is there any way to do the authentication from my script itself?

Comment: Shell Script? Nopes, you need either cUrl or Twurl.

Comment: ok, with CURL and PHP, is there any way to do it without depending on external tools?

Comment: if I do curl http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.xml?user_id=12863272,3191321,9160152,8285392, I get an authentication error

Comment: Basic authentication which you are using is not available anymore.

Comment: I didn't understand fully how I should use curl with oauth, I'll read through the oauth tutorial at twitter.  thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Apigee has a great console for playing around with the Twitter API (among others).

[Here is an example](http://app.apigee.com/console/apigee-console-snapshots-1293858000000_8de1accd-c38d-4faf-b205-b7f85eadb647/rendersnapshotview) for /users/lookup.